# Passing data (which got from backend API) between component got undefined in Angular

Tags: html, angular

> I have my parent components like this to get list of product by calling HTTP request and it works fine:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiServiceService } from 'src/app/api-service.service';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
            selector: 'app-show-products',
            templateUrl: './show-products.component.html',
            styleUrls: ['./show-products.component.css']
           })
export class ShowProductsComponent implements OnInit {
ProductsList:any =[];
pro:any;
ActiveEdit: boolean=false;
constructor(private service: ApiServiceService) {}
ngOnInit(): void{
this.refreshProductsList();
}
refreshProductsList(){
this.service.GetProductList().subscribe(data => {
  this.ProductsList=data;
})
}
EditProductClick(product:any){
  this.pro=product;
  this.ActiveEdit=true;
}
}
```

> And parent html like

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
  Create Product 
</button>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>ReleaseDate</th>
    <th>Discontinued</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Option</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let dataProduct of ProductsList">
        <td>{{dataProduct.id}}</td>
        <td>{{dataProduct.name}}</td>
        <td>{{dataProduct.description}}</td>
        <td>{{dataProduct.releaseDate}}</td>
        <td>{{dataProduct.discontinued}}</td>
        <td>{{dataProduct.rating}}</td>
        <td>{{dataProduct.price}}</td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" routerLink="Edit-Product" (click)="EditProductClick(dataProduct)" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                Edit
            </button>   
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light mr-1">
                Delete
            </button>
        </td>         
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="modal-body" style="display: none;" >
   <app-edit-products [Pro]="pro"></app-edit-products>
</div>
```

> And the problem is even I try to pass data by this way <app-edit-products [Pro]="pro"> I can get this data in child component, it is undefined in the console when I run the app

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-products',
templateUrl: './edit-products.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-products.component.css']
})
export class EditProductsComponent implements OnInit {
constructor() { }
@Input() Pro:any;
ngOnInit(): void {
console.log(this.Pro); <= this is undefined
}
```

> Did I do something wrong or is there any other way to pass data?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use some flag like below.

```
// Define isEdit variable first...

EditProductClick(product:any){
  this.isEdit = true;
  this.pro=product;
  console.log(this.pro);  // Check this comes proper or not...
  this.ActiveEdit=true;      
}
```

Then use this flag in HTML like this

```
 <div class="modal-body" style="display: none;" *ngIf="isEdit">
   <app-edit-products [Pro]="pro"></app-edit-products>
 </div>
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but it doesn't work, so sorry

Comment: @AnhMinhDiệp Thanks for update. As I have marked, we all are almost on same point to handle this issue. I'm surprised that, we all are wrong?

Comment: It is sad to say that I don't know, I can't figure out, and I decided to change the solution, use param and take data from that, and it work

Comment: Okay @AnhMinhDiệp :)

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your component even when you don't have an item selected.
You could do this:

```html
  <div class="modal-body" style="display: none;">
    <app-edit-products *ngIf="pro" [Pro]="pro"></app-edit-products>
  </div>
```

Or you chould implement the [OnChanges interface](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges).

Comment: this solution doesn't work, very sorry, but I have a little question about *ngIf="pro" what is this for ?

Comment: To remove the component till the `pro` property has value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal-body" style="display: none;" >
   <app-edit-products [Pro]="pro"></app-edit-products>
</div>
```

call to `app-edit-products` is in sync and executing before you are assigning value to `this.pro=product;` in the method `EditProductClick(product:any)`
So you can achieve what you want in one way that set a flag in `EditProductClick(product:any)` method as below
`this.proFlag = true;` and so your html call will be like below

```
<div class="modal-body" style="display: none;">
      <ng-container *ngIf="proFlag">
      <<app-edit-products [Pro]="pro"></<app-edit-products>
    </ng-container>
   </div>
```

Comment: I tried to add a flag like u say (I copy all your solution just fix the tag app-edit-component to app-edit-products) also I define the flag in EditProductClick(product:any) method and set it to true like this:  
`EditProductClick(product:any){
    this.isEdit = true;
    this.pro=product;
    console.log(this.pro);  
    this.ActiveEdit=true;      
  }`  
And it is still undefined

Comment: Have you added the flag in *ngIf condition in your html like this : <ng-container *ngIf="isEdit"><app-edit-products [Pro]="pro"></<app-edit-products></ng-container>

Comment: yes I am it is look like this:
`<div class="modal-body" style="display: none;">
    <ng-container *ngIf="isEdit">
    <app-edit-products [Pro]="pro"></app-edit-products>
    </ng-container>
</div>`

Comment: It should work I tried and it is working for me, what is this.ActiveEdit=true; ? try using this in ngIf instead isEdit

Comment: I tried to use this.ActiveEdit=true, its like when u click it will turn on, some kind of flag, I gave up and try to get data throught param, but someday if I found out, I will answer this, this is weird because I see many people try to pass data like this and its work for them